# Anaconda Navigator: "bytes" object has no attribute "get"

Tags: windows, anaconda

I am trying to open the anaconda navigator, I installed it but it did not work, and shows the message bytes object has no attribute get I have uninstall, and install again over and over, and nothing seems to work, help please

I already deleate all the files, and installed again, I uninstalled python, and vscode, I do not know what to do

[The image shows the message from anaconda, I do not have enough points to show the complete image yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM0AW.png)

Comment: For reference Anaconda issues: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/13298 and https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/13335

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/13298 is the same problem but he did not find a solution

Comment: See tips at the end of this issue related to checking your `.condarc` file. It may help to post the contents of this configuration file.  https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12610 (author there claims to have solved the problem but its hard to say what he did ...)

Comment: it did not work :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same situation as me. **What ended up working was deleting any nodeJS references from both local and system path variables.**

If you run "conda update anaconda-navigator" in Anaconda prompt it should error out and tell you which paths are breaking it. For me it was system32 and nodeJS so just got rid of nodeJS and all works fine now.

Previously tried fixes:

- Reinstalled
- Deleted .condarc
- Ran "conda --no-plugins update conda"